# Rails validate statement checking for blank content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in models/micropost.rb

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :content, length: { maximum: 140}
  validates :content, length: { minimum: 1 }
```

The first validation line is fine. However, in the second line I am trying to check for blank in content and something is going wrong? I think there's a problem with the multiple validates statements maybe? I'm pretty new to rails... :(

Comment: Why not have presence: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply validate presence:

```
validates :content, length: { maximum: 140 }, presence: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate `min` and `max` length by using `in` range

```
validates :content, length: { in: 1..140 }
```